# C# Add new object to array in a new object

Tags: c#

I have an object model that contains an Array of objects.  The model looks like this:

```
public Request()
{
     RequestId = String.Empty;
     Name = String.Empty;
     Loads = Array.Empty<Load>();
}
public Load()
{
     LoadId = String.Empty;
     IsLoaded = false;
}
```

I need to create a new Request() object but I am having trouble figuring out the proper way to add an object to the array portion.

This is what I have:

```
var requests = new List<Request>{
new Request(){
RequestId = "1",
Name = "ATLGA",
Loads= new Load[1]{Loads[0] = new Load{IsLoaded = true} }
}
```

I get an error: the name "Loads' does not exist in the current context. I have tried different syntax, but I am unable to figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you initialize your array to one object:

```
Loads = new[] {  new Load { IsLoaded = true } }
```